# Populate jquery select

Tags: jquery, json

I have been banging my head against the wall on this one and hope that some one can help. I'm populating a select box using **ajax**. which i have been able to do, but i can only seem to display the first value, the data is coming in a **json**. When I console log aData I get multiple values but I don't on the select list... any ideas?

```
$('.request-make').change(function () {
    var postVars = new Object();
    postVars.make = $('.request-make').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/car_search/get_model',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: postVars,
        cache: false,
        success: function (aData) {
            //alert(aData)  
            //console.log(aData)
            //$('#request-model').val(response.data);
            $('#makebox').get(0).options.length = 0;
            $('#makebox').get(0).options[0] = new Option("--Select--", "0");

            $.each(aData, function (i, item) {
                $('#makebox').get(0).options[$('#makebox').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item[i].data, item[i].data);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the spec for the $.each call:

> jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )

That being said, I suspect something is wrong here:

```
new Option(item[i].data, item[i].data);
```

Because, item will already be a different item each time.

Aren't you trying to do something like

```
new Option(item.data, item.data);
```

or even

```
new Option(aData[i].data, aData[i].data);
```

Comment: just tried to change the - new Option(item[i].data, item[i].data); to both the suggestion you have given the first returns no data and the secound comes back as undefined...

Comment: can you post somewhere the contents of `aData` ?

Comment: my mistake I had put my array in an array hence why i only got the first record. thank you so much for your help!